# Troubles reading after end of line in C

Tags: c, file, fgetc

So, I'm having trouble reading from my file.

I want to read this file ;

```
    1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The first 1 is my player, while the array is my game board.

So I'm trying to read all this using this code :

```
void initialize_file(Game *game)
{
    int i,j;
    FILE *file = fopen("save.sav", "r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't read file.... \n");
    }
    else
    {
        game->player=(fgetc(file)-'0');
        printf("Player %d loaded\n",jeu->player);
        fgetc(file); //jump the two lines after player
        fgetc(file);
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                Game->game[i][j] = (fgetc(file)-'0');
                printf("value : %d \n",Game->game[i][j]);
                fgetc(file);

            }
            fgetc(file);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I sometimes get values outside of my array like -16 and -38, which refer each to Space and LF.
So my question is : How could I avoid to run unto these -16 and -38 ?

Thanks a lot, and I am sorry in advance for any english mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does a blank exist after the last value on each line?

If the line ends with `'0\n'` instead of `'0 \n'`, the invocation of `fgetc` in the inner loop will read the `\n` the first time the loop terminates, and the outer loop will read the next character. This will cause your arithmetic to result in `' ' - '0'` many times, which is `32-48 = -16` on a system that uses a character encoding compatible with ASCII.

Similarly, `'\n' - '0'` is `10-48 = -38`. Your problem is that the last number on each line is not followed by a blank.

Either output a blank before the `\n` when you save your game board or remove the last invocation of `fgetc` since the inner loop already reads the `\n`.

Edit: As [cnicutar responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501907/troubles-reading-after-end-of-line-in-c#21501944), you should also be checking your return values.

Comment: Thanks ! I've added a blank before the \n and now it works alright. I'll be checking my return values as cnicutar said, indeed. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Every time you do an `c = fgetc(..)` check `c != EOF` and `isdigit(c)` before using it.

---

Word to the wise, `c` should be an `int`. But of course everyone knew that.